# spring security возвращает 302 found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Когда отправляю post с помощью `javascrit` и если такого пользователя нет, то `spring security` возвращает мне код `302 Found`. Как этого избежать. вот мои настройки
класс WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/style/**", "/js/**", "/font/**" ,"/", "/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    private MySQLUserDetailsService mySQLUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(mySQLUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

MySQLUserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class MySQLUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDetails loadedUser;

        try {
            User client = userService.getByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
            loadedUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    client.getEmail(), client.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                    client.getRoles());
        } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
        }
        return loadedUser;
    }

}
```

и rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/login")
public class AuthRest {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    EntityConverter entityConverter;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody JsonAuth user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String md5Hex = MD5Util.md5Custom(user.getPassword());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getLogin(), md5Hex);
        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationManager.authenticate(token));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entityConverter.userToDTO(userService.getCurrentUser()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleException(BadCredentialsException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ModelException("User not found"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил сам.
В классе `MySQLUserDetailsService` изменил выбрасываемый эсепшн

```
catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
    }
```

Заменил на

```
catch (UserNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```